# Cleaning up a class that contains the object it represents

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, game, tic-tac-toe

I've recently started writing a tic-tac-toe game (following the Odin project) and am trying to write a class to hold the board game.

What I'm not sure about, is that the board class holds all the data related to the board in a variable called `@board`. Now after thinking about it I decided that the `Board` class shouldn't know about the game logic, and just hold the board itself, but now I'm not sure if it's redundant or not.

Main problem is that right now, when I try to add logic to the Game class, I get a function that looks like this:

```
class Game
  .
  def is_over?
    board = @board.board
    .
    .
  end
end
```

Which just feels wrong...
my current implementation for it is like so:

```
module TicTacToe
  class Board
    attr_reader :board
    def initialize(size)
      @board = create_empty_board(size)
      @size = size
    end

    def print_board
      @size.times { print "-----" }
      puts
      @board.each do |row|
        row.each do |c|
          print "| #{c} |"
        end
      puts
      @size.times { print "-----" }
      puts
      end
    end

    def make_move(move, sym)
      if board[x][y] == ' '
        board[x][y] = sym
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "Invalid, cell not empty"
      end
    end

  private
    def create_empty_board(size)
      board = Array.new
      size.times do
        row = Array.new
        size.times do
          row << ' '
        end
        board << row
      end
      board
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post your `Game` class as well.

Comment: @200_success I don't really have a 'Game' class code to post, it's still in the making and I'm trying to think about how to build it, and this point is exactly where I got stuck.

Comment: `x` and `y` are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your `board.board` has a code smell, but it is hard to say what to do without knowing `Game`.

Actually `Board#board` is an array. I would recommend to add methods to `Board` that allow you to use the instance of `Board` instead of `Board#board`.

Example: To get a row of yor board you can use:

```
class Board
  ...
  def [](row) #Access to one row
    @board[row]
  end
  def each_row #loop on all rows...
    @board.each{|row| yield row }
  end

end

class Game
  ...
  def is_over?
    @board.each_row{|row|
     row.each{|field| } ##your check
    }
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: That's actually a really neat idea. I didn't think about that. Thanks :)